# Finding the root of a set of coupled non-linear equations in Python

Tags: python, optimization, root-finding

I am trying to solve a symplectic mapping problem and for that I need to evaluate the following non-linear equation:

[image]

In this case, I need to find the values of xi_{n+1} which make the left and the right hand side equal.

However, the problem is that the function H consists of taking partial derivatives with respect to the unknown variables xi_{n+1}. This is how the H function is specified:

[image]

This means that I need a non-linear solver which can couple the underlying equations for the gradient expression in H.

I have tried using `fsolve` from scipy in combination with the numerical evaluation of the gradient via the gradient function found within numpy.

This approach works for really small number of points. However, once I try to increase the number of points for which the updated xi_{n+1} need to be computed, `fsolve` just does not work anymore (at least the computation takes a significant amount of time).

I have tried using other nonlinear solvers from scipy but non of them really helped me in solving this issue.

Right now I have found a work-around in which I iterate over each point and find the updated xi_{n+1} coordinate but I would like to have an approach in which I can couple the expressions from adjacent points together, i.e, to solve the complete system simultaneously.

Any thoughts on how could I achieve this?

Comment: This cannot be answered until you show your existing code with some realistic sample data.

Comment: R and W are unspecified; you need to define them.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)